# "Throw a party" meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> I'll throw you a party

What does the above sentence means and how it is different from the sentence given below?

> I'll give you party

Answer (score 3):

To "throw a party" is the conventional, idiomatic way of saying that you will organize a fun get-together.

You can also say "we'll have a party". That's probably more common.

If someone else is organizing it and you merely attend, you say you are "going to a party".

Note it's "throw" and not "through" -- you have it right in the body of the question but wrong in the title.

We don't normally say "give a party". I suppose people would know what you meant, but it's not idiomatic. Note you'd need an article, "throw a party" or "give a party", not "throw party" or "give party".

Answer (score 0):

When you "throw" a party, the implication is that you are the host or organizer.  So if you say "I will throw you a party" it is the same as saying:

"I will host a party for you"

or

"I will organize a party for you"

The metaphor for "throwing" things about sounds less formal and stuffy.  It is a casual phrase meant to show you intend a good time, and not something boring and uptight.